# Rename file on upload PHP

Tags: php, file, upload, renaming

I am trying to build a script to upload and rename an image to a folder and store the path in my sql db.

Here is where I am at: The file get uploaded both to the folder and the pathname to the db but I cannot figure out how to rename the filename. Ideally I would like to make the filename unique so I don't duplicates.

```
<?php   
//preparing the patch to copy the uploaded file
$target_path = "upload/";

//adding the name of the file, finishing the path
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']); 

//moving the file to the folder
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
   echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']). 
   " has been uploaded";
} else{
  echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

//getting input from the form
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

//preparing the query to insert the values
$query = "INSERT INTO complete_table (name, description, picture) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '". $target_path ."')";

//opening connection to db
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if (!$link) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

 //selecting a db
mysql_select_db("wcs_venues", $link) or die(mysql_error());

//running the query
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

//closing the connection
mysql_close($link);

?>
```

I am new with all this and I am really trying but after looking at many tutorial and answered questions on Stack-overflow, I realized I needed help. Thank you in advance for helping this newbie.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried, and explain what didn't work. Renaming a file in PHP is something you could very easily google, where are you stuck?

Comment: You need to rename `$_FILES['picture']['name']`

Comment: Hello Jessica, I did google it and the closest I got to a solution was using this documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php but I could only and text after the extension of the image like "upload/nameofimage.pnghereistheextratext" which was not helpful in my case. I also tried creating a new variable with extra parameter and it only resulted in sql errors.

Comment: @Jessica, I hope you are not too disappointed by my attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is where you set the name of the file being saved:

```
$target_path = "upload/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']);
```

In this case, you're building the file name in the variable `$target_path`.  Just change that to something else.  What you change it to is up to you.  For example, if you don't care about the name of the file and just want it to always be unique, you could create a [GUID](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) or a [Unique ID](http://php.net/uniqid) and use that as the file name.  Something like:

```
$target_path = "upload/";
$target_path = $target_path . uniqid();
```

Note that this would essentially throw away the existing name of the file and replace it entirely.  If you want to keep the original name, such as for display purposes on the web page, you can store that in the database as well.

Comment: this works pretty good but it also kills the extension of the file... will that be a problem when I retrieve the path to display the image?

Comment: @the_arthemis: Not for displaying on the web, no.  File extensions don't actually mean anything.  As long as you're sending the correct `Content-Type` header when displaying the image, the browser will know what to do with it.  When the file is uploaded, it *should* contain the type here: `$_FILES['picture']['type']`, which you should store in the database with the other information about the file.

Comment: do you mean I need a separate column in my db to store the type?

Comment: @the_arthemis: That would be advisable, that way you'll be able to provide the browser with the file type when you serve the file later.

Comment: Well I don't know how I did it but I now get files renamed with '[uniqueid][originalname].[extension]' That said I have no clue how it happened.

Comment: ` //preparing the patch to copy the uploaded file
    $target_path = "upload/";
   $target_path = $target_path . uniqid();

//getting input from the form
  $name = $_POST['name'];
   $description = $_POST['description'];


    //adding the name of the file, finishing the path
   $target_path = $target_path . $_FILES["file"]. basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']); 

   //moving the file to the folder
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], "$target_path")) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded";
  }`

Answer (score 1):

First get the file extension:

```
$file_extension = strrchr($uploaded_file_name, ".");
```

Then rename the uploaded file with a **unique id** + **file extension**

```
$uploaded_file_name = uniqid() . $file_extension;
```

**Example:**

[image]

**TIP:** Save the original file name and other information in a database.

Answer (score 0):

First get the extension with `pathinfo()`

Then create your unique name:

```
$name = 'myname'.uniqid();
```

Then rename your file.

```
$target_path = $target_path . $name.$ext);
```

move_upload_file takes the second parameters $destination, its where you are inserting the target_path ( where your file is going to be saved with that given name ).